Create mapping based on enums including enforcing compiler errors
I need to enforce a mapping on an object. The aim is to create a type or interface which maps from ANIMAL_PLACE to ANIMAL_TYPE. This type I then want to use to create an object of the needed key:value pairs. But, I need the compiler to throw an error when I forget to add either ANIMAL_PLACE or ANIMAL_TYPE to object. I am only able to get it halfway done.
export enum ANIMAL_TYPE {
    dog = "dog",
    cat = "cat",
    fish = "fish",
    foo = "foo"
}

export enum ANIMAL_PLACE {
        europe = 'europe',
        africa = 'africa',
        asia = "asia"
}

// This does not throw a compiler error when I forget to add ANIMAL_PLACE nor ANIMAL_TYPE to type
type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog]
}



// this only throws a compiler error when I forget to add ANIMAL_PLACE to record
const AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapRecord: Record<ANIMAL_PLACE, ANIMAL_TYPE[]> = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish],
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog],
};

Here is a Playground
If it is not possible to throw a compiler error when either of the two changes, is there a way get a compiler error, when I forget to include one of ANIMAL_TYPE instead of ANIMAL_PLACE...?

You might be looking for some static assertion that ANIMAL_TYPE extends keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType and that ANIMAL_PLACE extends AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType[ANIMAL_TYPE][number]?

You can write a type to verify the intended requirements so that you get errors when they aren't met. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz this is what I am looking for. Could you also explain in your answer, how to use namespace as a type for an object?

"How to use namespace as a type for an object?" I'm not sure what you're talking about. The namespace thing is an internal module which lets me write the same type name multiple times without conflicting. It's just for demonstration of the three different scenarios.

You can write a utility type to require that two types are "the same" (although the test I write actually just make it require that the two types are mutually assignable, which is good enough for your purposes):
type Same<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = void;

This doesn't evaluate to anything important (Same<T, U> always evaluates to void), but the constraints on T and U make it so that if you write Same<T, U> with different types, either T or U will cause a compiler error:
type T1 = Same<string, string>; // okay
type T2 = Same<string, number>; // error!
//             ~~~~~~
// Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'.
type T3 = Same<"abc", string>; // error!
//                    ~~~~~~
// Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint '"abc"'.

(Note that conceptually it would be type Same<T extends U, U extends T> = void, but TypeScript rejects that as an illegally circular constraint. The workaround is to have U extends V, where V is a third type parameter which defaults to T. So when you use Same<T, U>, it's like writing Same<T, U, T>, and then TS will complain if U extends T is false.)
So then we can make sure that the union of AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType's keys is identical to ANIMAL_PLACE type, and that the union of AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType's array element types are identical to ANIMAL_TYPE:
type VerifyMap =
    Same<keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType, ANIMAL_PLACE> &
    Same<AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType[keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType][number], ANIMAL_TYPE>

Note that AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType[keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType] is the union of values of AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType, since it's an indexed access with a union of keys. We expect that to be a union of array/tuple types, so indexing into that with number gives us the union of their element types.

So, if we have defined AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType correctly, then you won't get any errors:
type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.asia]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.foo]
}

type VerifyMap =
    Same<keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType, ANIMAL_PLACE> &
    Same<AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType[keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType][number], ANIMAL_TYPE> // okay

If you are missing an element from ANIMAL_PLACE then you get an error on the first check:
type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog, ANIMAL_TYPE.foo]
}

type VerifyMap =
    Same<keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType, ANIMAL_PLACE> & // error!
    Same<AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType[keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType][number], ANIMAL_TYPE>

And if you're missing an element from ANIMAL_TYPE then you get an error on the second check:
type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.asia]: []
}

type VerifyMap =
    Same<keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType, ANIMAL_PLACE> &
    Same<AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType[keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType][number], ANIMAL_TYPE> // error!


So that's the basic approach I would take to enforce out-of-band constraints on your types. The VerifyMap above might not be sufficient for every possible check of AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType; it checks for missing an extra things, but it doesn't force there not to be repeats. You could write a check for that too, such as by requiring the intersection of all the array elements of the property values have no overlap:
type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.asia]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.foo, ANIMAL_TYPE.cat], // repeat
}

type APAMT = AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType;
type ISect = { [K in keyof APAMT]: { [P in keyof APAMT]:
    P extends K ? never : APAMT[P][number] & APAMT[K][never]
}[keyof APAMT] }[keyof APAMT]

type VerifyMap =
    Same<keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType, ANIMAL_PLACE> &
    Same<AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType[keyof AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType][number], ANIMAL_TYPE> &
    Same<ISect, never>; // error!

I won't go into detail for how that works as it's outside the scope of the question as asked. The point is that you can usually write some kind of utility type to check the invariants you want to impose.
Playground link to code

Wow... Still so much to learn about the types in TS. Thanks a lot

One question though. I understand this bit in Same<T extends U, U extends V>, but why V = T?

It would be T extends U, U extends T in a perfect world, but that's illegally circular. I've edited the answer to explain this bit.

type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish]
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog]
}

This type is declared to match the value it is equal to.
There is no relationship between the keys of the type, and the values of the type.
It would be clearer to say that the type is what it's value is.
Because of this, you don't have any errors, since the type is correct and nothing is to be inferred.
However, when you declare a Record<ANIMAL_PLACE, ANIMAL_TYPE[]>, then you must declare something for all the entries of ANIMAL_PLACE.
In this case, it fails because you did not declare anything for the keys ANIMAL_PLACE.asia.
You can bypass this by declaring your const as:
const AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapRecord: { [K in ANIMAL_PLACE]?: ANIMAL_TYPE[]} = {
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.africa]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.cat, ANIMAL_TYPE.fish],
    [ANIMAL_PLACE.europe]: [ANIMAL_TYPE.dog],
};

This way, all keys are optional. However, this also means you will need to perform some typechecking since you don't know which keys are used and which are not.

If you want to flip it, and ensure a compiler error occurs when you forget to include one of ANIMAL_TYPE, you can do it like so:
type AnimalTypeToAnimalPlaceMap = Record<ANIMAL_TYPE, ANIMAL_PLACE[]>;


There is no type inference in the definition of the type?

Correct, for some reason, I read type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType = {...}as type AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapType: {...}, update the response to make sense, good catch.

This type AnimalTypeToAnimalPlaceMap = Record<ANIMAL_TYPE, ANIMAL_PLACE>; does take ANIMAL_PLACE, but I need ANIMAL_PLACE[] which is basically the same I have const AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapRecord: Record<ANIMAL_PLACE, ANIMAL_TYPE[]> =..., or am I mistaken?

I updated response to have type AnimalTypeToAnimalPlaceMap = Record<ANIMAL_TYPE, ANIMAL_PLACE[]>
They aren't the same. One uses the ANIMAL_PLACE as the key to the object, while the others use the ANIMAL_TYPE. This means that their relationship is inverted.
In type AnimalTypeToAnimalPlaceMap you are saying that every animal must belong to at least one place.
In const AnimalPlaceToAnimalMapRecord you are saying that every place contains x animals.
Logically speaking, they are different.
